# Simple javascript suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress

UPDATE: THERE ARE 12 of these on one page. Only the last one works. They all have unique ID's and a unique function written for them though.

This simple function is working on my development site but not my live site for some reason. It is a wordpress install but they should be exactly the same setup. I haven't written additional functions or anything. Any ideas? I thought maybe a plugin was stopping it but after testing that hasn't been the case. I have no idea how to troubleshoot javascript using developer tools.

```
function quantChange() {
    d = document.getElementById("bwoo-quantity-187").value;
    document.getElementById("187").setAttribute('data-quantity',d);
}
```

Input being used

```
<select class='quantity' onchange='quantChange()' id='bwoo-quantity-187'>
    <option value=0>0</option>
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=4>4</option>
    <option value=5>5</option>
    <option value=6>6</option>
    <option value=7>7</option>
    <option value=8>8</option>
    <option value=9>9</option>
    <option value=10>10</option>
</select>
```

Item I'm trying to change:

```
<form action="/order-now/a-la-carte/?add-to-cart=187" class="cart-nonmealplan" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="submit" id="187" data-product_id="187" data-product_sku="" data-quantity="1" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

Comment: "I have no idea how to troubleshoot javascript using developer tools." -- I would start here https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: In your developer tools, go to the Console tab and see if there are any errors that show.

Comment: `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. ` That's the only error showing which also shows on the development site.

Comment: You can not use `107` as an `id`. Also you forgot to declare your variables before using (won't cause much problems though.)

Comment: Why is that? It works fine on the other install.

Comment: @brs14ku: You can ignore that one. What is your DOCTYPE? Try declaring `d` with `var`. Other than that, there's not much info in your 3 lines of code to know what's going on...

Comment: According to the [HTML5 spec](http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/283863), you cannot start an `id` with a number.

Comment: Tried declaring var d. Didn't change anything. Doctype = `<!DOCTYPE html>
`

Comment: You should quote the option's value attributes. Also, `"bwoo-quantity-187" != "bwoo-quantity-107"`

Comment: Sorry, they are quoted but for some reason in the Page source view they are not.

Comment: Ilia those were pulled from two different parts of the page at different times. I'll edit the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID can't contain numbers as first symbol. May be the problem in that? 
http://jsfiddle.net/3zJDt/4/ See working example.

HTML

```
<select class='quantity' onchange='quantChange()' id='bwoo-quantity-187'>
    <option value=0>0</option>
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
    <option value=4>4</option>
    <option value=5>5</option>
    <option value=6>6</option>
    <option value=7>7</option>
    <option value=8>8</option>
    <option value=9>9</option>
    <option value=10>10</option>
</select>

<form action="/order-now/a-la-carte/?add-to-cart=187" class="cart-nonmealplan" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="submit" id="p187" data-product_id="p187" data-product_sku="" data-quantity="1" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple">Add to cart</button>
</form>

<script>
function quantChange() {
    var d = document.getElementById("bwoo-quantity-187").value;
    document.getElementById("p187").setAttribute('data-quantity',d);
}    
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have an effect on the development site. I'll look at tha tthough.

Comment: You have to understand difference, you shouldn't place code that you don't understand, to any of your websites dev or live. Problem is inside IDs, you need to set up elemen ID properly.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Interestingly enough it still doesn't work. Does that mean some other script is interfering somehow?

Comment: Better solution is to have 1 function. that will get parameter. then function1()
function2()
funtion3()

You can create one function updateCartQuantity(el) {

document.getElementById("p" + el.value) //you can get value of youe select field here
}

Comment: Nailed it finally. Thanks!